# php defined named constant as a function name

Tags: php, function, constants

How to create a dynamic function name dependent on a defined named constant?

eg:

```
define('NAME1','func1');

function NAME1($arg) {
    echo "function 1 $arg\n";
    print __FUNCTION__." in ".__FILE__." at ".__LINE__."\n";
};

NAME1("helllo");
```

this echos function name as "NAME1" - why is it not func1?

Comment: Constants and functions have separate identifier lookup tables.

Comment: Design-wise this seems like a Bad Idea™. What's the use case?

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing that I can think of is to use [PHP 5.3 anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (other than using `eval`)

```
define('NAME1', 'my_function');
$func_name = NAME1;
$$func_name = function($arg) {
   // Your code
};
$my_function('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

```
this echos function name as "NAME1" - why is it not func1?
```

because you defined your function name as `NAME1`.